# Groovy ant task: Specifiying additional groovy files

Tags: ant, groovy

In our ANT build files we sometimes call groovy scripts

```
<groovy src="${groovy.script.dir}/DoIt.groovy"/>
```

Is there a way to specify one or more additional Groovy files? Our use case is that we define some constants in a separate that should be used in several scripts.

Do we have to compile your scripts to .class files in order to use them as intended, or is there a groovier way of achieving our goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) for the `<groovy>` task say that when you specify the `src` attribute:

> The directory containing the file is added to the classpath

So other groovy classfiles in the same folder should be accessible from the script you declare.

Is this not working?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It works, but... package declarations are handled strangely. It works for me when 1) I omit declaring a package for my root script and 2) reference other classes  without qualifying their package. Fully qualified names do not seem to work - in some cases.

Comment: @jens Maybe try setting the `classpath` attribute as well?

Comment: Can't imagine that this could help. We are not using compiled versions but have only groovy scripts in our directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue in the past, using Groovy 1.8.1. I couldn't find in the documentation how to use several script files within the same `<groovy>` task (see also the ant `<script>` task's doc). Using several  tasks didn't work either for me, because the context was reset between them.

I haven't upgraded to Groovy 2.x.y as I don't use it that much. Below I illustrate a possible workaround with 1.8.1; perhaps it's still valid.

```
<property name="home" location="/Users/coyote/mytest/ant/src"/>
<property name="gscript1" location="${home}/my/own/pack/foo.groovy"/>
<property name="gscript2" location="${home}/my/own/pack/bar.groovy"/>

<groovy>
  evaluate( new File(properties.'gscript1') );
  evaluate( new File(properties.'gscript2') );
</groovy>
```

`evaluate()` takes either a String or a Script file, on which it performs a dynamic evaluation -according to the API doc- using the current bindings. Those are the bindings of the `<groovy>` task, I presume.

I'm not sure I understand your use case, but with this model you can of course define constants first; hardcoded, as properties + code, or in a groovy-script-file + evaluate.